# How to detect Visual Studio debug execution context from within code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm looking for a way to detect how code is called during a debugging session in Visual Studio. Trying to differentiate these two contexts:

- Ordinary debugging, whether running or single stepping.
- Called via the debugger itself, such as my ToString being called from the watch window.

(I'm doing this because I have some non-release thread validation code I want to disable in the second case.)

Anyone have a way to do this, or ideas about things to pursue? I'm fine with hacky, tricksy methods, even if they are specific to a particular version of VS.

Things that don't work:

- *Grabbing a StackTrace and looking for something magic that means the debugger is calling in, rather than regular code.* VS uses the current thread in its current state to call out of for the Watch window, so all the StackTrace is going to see is the current stack at the debugger breakpoint + the getter/ToString that the Watch window is calling, right on top of it.

Answer (score 2):

This situation typically arises when methods that Visual Studio assumes are pure (i.e. evaluation has no impact on the state of the program) either have side effects or have preconditions that the debugger violates.

These situations are best solved using the following tools:

- [DebuggerBrowsableAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggerbrowsableattribute.aspx): Apply this attribute to properties:

  ```
  [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
  ```

  - Apply to all properties whose `get` method is not pure, i.e. the getter alters the state of the program, either through setting a cached value or otherwise
  - Apply to all properties whose `get` method has preconditions the debugger could violate, such as threading restrictions, cross-thread invocations (don't forget implicit if you use COM interop)
- [DebuggerDisplayAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggerdisplayattribute.aspx): Apply this attribute to all types whose `ToString()` implementation performs non-trivial operations (avoid debugger performance impact) or has preconditions the debugger might not meet (e.g. threading requirements). This attribute is used *instead* of calling `ToString()` for these types.
- [DebuggerTypeProxyAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggertypeproxyattribute.aspx): Apply this attribute to types that require special consideration for when, what, and how information is presented in the debugger. The .NET framework itself uses this attribute extensively to provide features like clear output for the `List<T>` and `HashMap<T>` types, and even to improve information available for types like `Lazy<T>` that are sometimes OK to evaluate and other times could affect the state of the program.

Comment: For small projects this might work, but for ours I need a different solution. Using Debugger attributes would require flagging every class with properties that may call down to the validation code with an attribute and an alternate type proxy that bypasses the validation code. That's too much work for the thousands of cases we have. I'm interested in something I can put in that validation code that looks upwards to see how it's being called, and tell it not to validate if it detects it's in a condition where one of those Debugger*Attributes would apply.

Comment: @ScottBilas Is it possible for you to call [Debugger.NotifyOfCrossThreadDependency()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.notifyofcrossthreaddependency.aspx) at the beginning of your validation code? It's possible this could solve your problem.

Comment: Wasn't aware of that function, neato. Unfortunately, it won't help. The validation code doesn't use multiple threads.

Comment: @ScottBilas If it were me, and the codebase were as large as you say, I would write an analyzer to locate properties that directly or indirectly invoke the validation routines in question and apply the `DebuggerBrowsableAttribute` to them. I would then use the other attributes only as I encountered a need for them to improve the debugging experience. This strategy treats reliability as low-hanging fruit, followed by improved features only when they are actually needed for something.

Comment: I appreciate the proposal, but there are likely thousands of these, which means maintenance pain. Plus it's a lot of clutter in the code. I really would like to try solving this from the bottom up, though I am finally coming round to the idea that it's not possible, given how the debugger appears to work.

Answer (score 1):

As far as ordinary debugging goes, I think this is what you want:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached
```

Here's the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.isattached%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

This won't help with the watch window though. <s>On this, maybe the `StackTrace` class can help but I haven't tried it myself. It's in the same namespace.</s>

Comment: That won't tell you if the code is being called from the watch window, just that a debugger is attached